# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[x]{3^x+7^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate the limit: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[x]{3^x+7^x}$$

I'm pretty much clueless on how to approach this. I've tried using the identity of $c^x = e^{x \cdot \ln(c)}$ but that led me to nothing. Also I've tried replacing $x$ with $t=\frac{1}{x}$ such that I would end up with $\lim_{t\to 0} (3^{1/t} + 7^{1/t})^{1/t}$ however I've reached yet again a dead end.

Any suggestions or even hints on what should I do next?

Comment: [Don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189).

Comment: @GNUSupporter Thanks for the tip, will remember for later posts :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\sqrt[x]{3^x+7^x}=7\sqrt[x]{1+(3/7)^x}=7\cdot \large{e^{\frac{\log{1+(3/7)^x}}{x}}}\to7$$

Comment: Ah okay I see what you did there. The left part (first part) of the equation got me stuck a bit but I understand it now. Didn't think of it that way. Thanks for clarifying it!

Comment: @0rka To be more clear, we can also consider an intermediate step $$\sqrt[x]{3^x+7^x}=\sqrt[x]{7^x}\sqrt[x]{(3^x/7^x)+1}$$

Comment: Yes, this is more clear. Thanks!1

Comment: @0rka You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[x]{7^x}\le \sqrt[x]{3^x +7^x}\le \sqrt[x]{2\cdot 7^x}$. Now squeeze.

Comment: Interesting observation! I've tried looking for some values to use the squeeze rule with, but couldn't find anything useful. What you suggested makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is the same as

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} 7 \sqrt[x]{1 + (3/7)^x}$$

and $|3/7| < 1$. What can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

it is $$7\cdot \sqrt[x]{\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^x+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\log(3^{x}+7^{x})^{1/x}=\log 7\left(\left(\dfrac{3}{7}\right)^{x}+1\right)^{1/x}=\log 7+\dfrac{\log((3/7)^{x}+1)}{x}=\cdots
\end{align*}

Perhaps,
\begin{align*}
1\leq\left((3/7)^{x}+1\right)^{1/x}\leq(1+1)^{1/x}=2^{1/x},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
7\leq(3^{x}+7^{x})^{1/x}=7((3/7)^{x}+1)^{1/x}\leq 7\cdot 2^{1/x},
\end{align*}
and $7\cdot 2^{1/x}\rightarrow 7$, then Squeeze Theorem concludes.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

Let $x>0.$

$ 7 \lt 7(1+(3/7)^x)^{1/x} \lt 7(2)^{1/x}$.

And now consider $x \rightarrow \infty$.